# Test of equality of means if the data is from poisson distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution

Suppose I have a data from Center A and Center B. I record the number of arrivals per hour(0,1,2,3,4,5) for center A and center B. I need to test whether the means from two centers are equal. My data has three columns. First column is Number of arrivals per hour, second column is center A frequency and last column is center B frequency. I also assume that the distribution of arrivals at both centers are Poisson.

Can I use a z test in this case?

Comment: How large are your sample sizes?  If your samples are not large you could always use a Wilcoxon rank sum test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) as a nonparametric alternative to the $t$-test.  Just be aware that the hypothesis you are testing with the rank sum test is slightly different than the hypothesis considered by the $t$-test.

Comment: 350 in center A and 400 in center B.

Comment: In that case you are probably fine using a $t$-test.  Also remember that the Poisson distribution itself is well-approximated by a Gaussian for large $\lambda$.

Comment: Okay. But in my case the sample mean for center A is about 2.31 and for center B is 2.60. Would it still be okay to use t -test?

Comment: That information is not consistent with a Poisson assumption, for center B ought then to be observing about 5% (or 20) hours with more than five arrivals per hour.

Comment: Yes, the underlying distributions need not be normal if your sample sizes are large.